# custom kernel in e1071

Tags: c++, r, svm

i am currently trying to tune the `svm` function in the `e1071` package for `R`. my input is genomic data (that is each attribute takes a value in the set {-1, 0, 1}) and none of the four kernels currently offered in the package is really good for this kind of data --- i would like to use Hamming distance as my kernel instead.

the `svm` function, it seems, is written in `C++`. i have downloaded the source via

```
download.packages(pkgs = "e1071", 
    destdir = ".",
    type = "source")
```

found the `svm.cpp` file containing code for the function and the corresponding kernel portion, where i can potentially add my own custom kernel. has anyone tried doing this? is it possible to do this? once i've finished modifying `svm.cpp` (provided i figure out how..), how do i make the package "see" the modified file?

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the existing kernel.
I changed the return statement of radial kernel to make the changes.. 
You can try with that

Comment: i don't see how your answer is helpful